# Extracting outputs of different length from lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Could anyone help me to sort out this problem. I am using `lapply` in a following code provided by @Arun:

```
out <- lapply(1:length(f1), function(f.idx) { 
  df1 <- read.delim(f1[f.idx], header = T) 
  df2 <- read.delim(f2[f.idx], header = T) 
  df3 <- read.delim(f3[f.idx], header = T) 

  idx.v <- get_idx(df1) 
  result <- get_result(idx.v, df2, df3)

})
```

Now, `out` is a list of 110 files. These output files are of different lengths, so I cannot use `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, out))`.
Is there a way to save each file as separate file in loop-like manner or do I have to do it manually (e.g., `out[1]`, `out[2]` etc ...).

Comment: I wonder if `plyr:::rbind.fill` is what you're after?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, its just that each file represents separate species and has different length (i.e number or observations), If I try to make one data frame then it is hard to tell the number of observations for each species. For further analysis I need to know exactly the number of observations for each species. If I some how able to save all these files in the list as separate files than things would be much easier for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @mariariaz then you would need to introduce another variable - species name. That would be very easy to work with later on (you could, i.e. split the data frame according to species).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve by `do.call(rbind...`? That is for combining data in a list. I'm not sure why you would stick an "`as.data.frame`" in there. If you have a `list` of `data.frame`s with the same columns, but the number of rows differ and you essentially want to "stack" those `data.frame`s on top of each other, then you should be able to use the following to get one big `data.frame` and then save that single object:

```
do.call(rbind, out)
```

It sounds like you have different `data.frame`s in a list named "out" and are trying to save your `data.frame`s as individual files in your working directory. If that is the case, try something like:

```
lapply(names(out), 
       function(x) write.csv(out[[x]], 
                             file = paste(x, ".csv", sep = "")))
```

If the names of the `data.frame`s in the list are not unique, you might need to take a different approach.

If you link to your earlier related questions, that might be better than simply mentioning who shared the code with you.

Comment: As, I have different data. frames in a list named "out", so I tried your suggestion but its not working and its just giving me, "list()" in console and no files in the working directory. I think it is because that names of the data.frames are not unique